# add updatable image in bottom navigation with text

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

[image]

Hi, M new in development area and want to create a bottom navigation in my app like in the image.

I want to add a text view with my bottom navigation which can be updated with some action, here 28 can be updated upto any number (0 to 999)
 How can custom bottom navigation can be made like this?
Thankx in advance.

Comment: you can use this lib https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation or this https://github.com/chandrahasan/BadgeView-Android/

Comment: You can also check out Bottom Navigation from Android's official Design Support Library.

Comment: if you need to crate your own custom without using any lib contact me  id i will share you a project

Comment: @NileshRathod can you send me the project at swataggarwal@gmail.com